# How to fix these memory leaks on my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to fix these memory leaks?

Leaked Objects
Malloc 80 Bytes
NSURL
__NSCFString
__NSCFString
Malloc 32 Bytes
NSURL
Malloc 16 Bytes
Malloc 96 Bytes
__NSCFArray
Malloc< varying sizes>

All of the leaked objects's responsible is libdyld.dylib responsivle frame is dlopen

When I ran the project on the iPhone simulator, there was no such a problem. When I ran this project on my iPad, this problem appears.

I'm using xCode4.4 with ios 5.0 sdk. My iPad is on iOS 5.1.1.

Why the problem appears? How to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you use ARC? You should upgrade to Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0. Run the static analyzer. Maybe it isn't even your fault, but part of the library.

Comment: Yes, I was also going to recommend the static analyzer.  Really useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I know its two years from now but some people might just do what i did. There is a newer version of libdyld.dylib called libdyld.dylib.1.1.3. I removed the reference of my active project and added the new version and boom no more leaks!